# I have a question about an SQL Command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
 string findUsersID = "SELECT ThreadsID FROM Threads";
```

I want every ID selected from the threads table in the opposite order. So instead of starting to retrieve the first id (when i call read.Read()). I want it to call the last ID and got the the previous..and so on with each READ() call.

How could I re-write the statement to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 string findUsersID = "SELECT ThreadsID FROM Threads ORDER BY ThreadsId DESC";
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider adding an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT ThreadsID FROM Threads ORDER BY ThreadsID desc
```

Note: Databases don't store the order in which records are added.  A table is an unordered set.  There is no guarantee that a query without an order by will return rows in a consistent order.